# Reemplazar corchetes por etiquetas html

Tags: php, html, regex

Tengo un texto

```
 {n}OBJECTIU: {n}
```

y necesito reemplazar `{n}OBJECTIU:{n}` con `<strong>OBJECTIU:</strong>` he intentado con `$post2 = preg_replace('/{n}(.*?){n}/', '/<strong>(.*?)</strong>/', $post1);`

Pero no he tenido suerte

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes mal el selector del texto que quieres dejar. Es decir, el selector (.*?) pasa a ser ${1} para que mantenga el texto, así:

```
<?php

$text = '{n}OBJECTIU: {n}';
echo $text_final = preg_replace('/{n}(.*?){n}/', '<strong>${1}</strong>', $text);

?>
```

La DOC de php no es demasiado clara, échale un vistazo a esto: https://lzone.de/examples/PHP%20preg_replace

Espero haberte ayudado!
Bona tarda!

Comment: Perfecto Un millón de gracias